# Storing Undo and Redo information to the database?

Tags: django, database-design, django-models

I've been wondering about this for a while and I haven't yet come up with a solution for it. On MySQL, I'd create a TRIGGER to automate saving revisions when changes happen and persist change values to the database to track revisions.

The question I have now is: how I can implement this in a more generic sense across most of my models in Django? Right now, I have just over 20 models and it's quickly growing. Generating objects to store all of these items will multiply my models by at least 2 and doesn't seem to be too optimal.

Is there a way I can automate this and make it a bit smarter and less cumbersome?

Comment: The SQL is also per-table trigger and per-table history of changes.  Since the Django solution you're talking about is the same complexity as the SQL, what's the big concern?

Comment: I'm new to triggers, just doing what I can. I didn't know you could trigger off of entire databases.

Comment: "trigger off of entire databases?"  What does this mean?  Your trigger will require a trigger and a table for every single table in the SQL schema (or "model" to use Django terminology).  It's not simpler than the obvious way to do it in Django.  Why did you post all the SQL code if it's not simpler?

Comment: I posted the SQL so as to demonstrate that I needed a way to loop in before items were saved and write both their previous state and current state into tables in the database. Sorry if that was confusing, I'm still learning Django.

Comment: So the SQL is completely useless, then?  Could you consider removing it and summarizing what you want.  
"
I needed a way to loop in before items were saved and write both their previous state and current state" seems clear and precise without the confusing overhead of a lot of SQL.  What's wrong with simply providing user stories about when you'd gather this data and when you'd use it?  Why post SQL?

Comment: Look, I'm really sorry, I'll change it. Everything's going to be okay.

Comment: "Everything's going to be okay"?  The important thing is "what are you trying to do?"  Okay isn't interesting.  What's interesting is a clear statement of the problem you're trying to solve without a bunch of confusing junk.  Simplicity and focus are important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [django-reversion](https://github.com/etianen/django-reversion).